# C# VSTO Excel Add-in to scroll when press arrow button

Tags: excel, vsto

I'm writing an Excel Add-in with description like this:

You know when you select a cell from the last row on the screen, when you press down arrow button on the keyboard, the document is scrolled one line: images:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDaUQ.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhJl9.png)

Now the Add-in has this property: even you select the cell of a row from the middle of the screen, the document always scroll one line when you press the down arrow button: images:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAg9p.png)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDNsk.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Dear @STHOH, I asked for help with that description. Thank you.